# WPF, Whats with this weird whitespace in Tooltip/Border

Tags: wpf, styles

I have styled a tooltip like

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="White" />
        </Border>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And it gets rendered like

[image]

Whats that white "rectangle" about? How can I get rid of it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That rectangle comes from the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToolTip` control wich will contain whatever you set in `Control.ToolTip`. You have to override it:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reducing the padding of the tooltip directly:

```
<ToolTip Padding="0" >
...
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works 100%. Sincerely, Davidqp.
Paste it inside a button:

````
                            <ToolTip Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">

                                <Border CornerRadius="10"
                                        BorderBrush="#your-color"
                                        Background="#your-color">
                                    <Grid Height="your-height">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="Images/logo.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="yout-text"
                                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                                               FontSize="11"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Button.ToolTip>```
````

Comment: Can you explain what you did?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).